# How to link the library with "-force_load" in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker-flags

My other libraries not allow me to set -ObjC or all_load flags.
So I need to use -force_load to link my library.

I have "GoogleOpenSource.framework" & "GooglePlus.framework" under my project, so how can I map those correctly to work.

I have set paths like this:

```
-force_load $(PROJECT_DIR)/Project_name/GooglePlus.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GooglePlus.h

-force_load $(PROJECT_DIR)/Project_name/GoogleOpenSource.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GoogleOpenSource.h
```

under the Other linker flags, but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue, but finally i fixed this by below mentioned steps:-

Steps

1. Go to the "other linker flags" inside your project's build settings and then
2. Add `-force_load $(PROJECT_DIR)/yourframewokname.framework/yourframeworkname`

Note** The framework which requires to add -ObjC flag inside the other linker flag in that case it conflicts with other libraries so in this case you need to force load the library which requires -ObjC.

Use above mentioned steps it works.

Answer (score 1):

`-force_load` flag is for loading static libraries, so you put the library archive, **NOT** the header file as the parameter.

Use the following instead:

```
-force_load GooglePlus.framework/Versions/Current/GooglePlus
-force_load GoogleOpenSource.framework/Versions/Current/GoogleOpenSource
```