# Why i need to set Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true) if it is true as default ? Firebase + iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics, ios14.5

Since my last update firebase dashboard is almost empty.
At first I did think is new iOS 14.5 policy problem but refer to:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/supporting-ios-14

I play around with settings and noticed that when I use

`Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)`

Firebase starts to provide data in real time as i have -FIRDebugEnabled.
But without calling it, I don't get firebase logs even in console looks like they are not send at all.
Why I need to `Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)` if there is information This setting is persisted across app sessions. By default it is enabled ?
Or I am just missing something?

In that time I did update pods to newest version for:

```
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this might be caused by the linker. Especially since `FIRAnalytics` is not used anywhere in your project and simply is not linked into the main binary. Then Firebase framework detects that there are no `FIRAnalytics` class and is not initiating analytics:
([FIRApp.m](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/c105a0de10726acb4daf1ec6dc29a7fcd9aea4a6/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRApp.m#L351))

```
- (BOOL)configureCore {
  [self checkExpectedBundleID];
  if (![self isAppIDValid]) {
    return NO;
  }

  // Initialize the Analytics once there is a valid options under default app. Analytics should
  // always initialize first by itself before the other SDKs.
  if ([self.name isEqualToString:kFIRDefaultAppName]) {
    Class firAnalyticsClass = NSClassFromString(@"FIRAnalytics");
    if (firAnalyticsClass) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
      SEL startWithConfigurationSelector = @selector(startWithConfiguration:options:);
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
      if ([firAnalyticsClass respondsToSelector:startWithConfigurationSelector]) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        [firAnalyticsClass performSelector:startWithConfigurationSelector
                                withObject:[FIRConfiguration sharedInstance].analyticsConfiguration
                                withObject:_options];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
      }
    }
  }
```

As I see there are two possible solutions:

1. Use `FIRAnalytics`(for Objective-C) or `Analytics`(for Swift) from `FirebaseAnalytics` somewhere in your main binary to force the linker to link it.
2. Use some linker flag to force link `FirebaseAnalytics` lib. This could be [-ObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629979/what-does-the-objc-linker-flag-do), [-force_load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580245/how-to-link-the-library-with-force-load-in-xcode) or even [-all_load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do).

I'd personally go with the first option because after some time you will use that class to log your custom events anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps disable collection in your plist file?  Doing so would require you to override the setting at runtime in order to enable analytics collection. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection#objective-c

Comment: I have only IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED is set to 0 & IS_ADS_ENABLED as well, but referring to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549074/firebase-for-ios-googleservice-info-plist-property-is-analytics-enabled-set-t) it should not have any impact on this, tested that as well before. But i disable console logs at runtime scheme by adding '-FIRDebugDisabled' at run argument seems like this have no impact as well.